# Confusión con constructores

Tags: java, poo

Soy nueva en POO, y tengo la siguiente duda: 
No diferencio **cuando** hacer estas dos cosas:

- `Persona humana = new Persona();`
- `public Persona (String nombre, int edad);`

¿Por qué a ambos se le llama constructores? Si instanciar una clase es crear un objeto mediante un constructor, cual seria la diferencia en hacer una u otra cosa? `new Persona` está inicializando? 
Me confunde muchisimo la verdad, y no distingo cuándo es que tengo que hacer cada cosa en mi programa.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estás mezclando 2 conceptos, el 1º es la declaración de la clase y el 2º es el uso:

```
Persona humana = new Persona( );
```

Aquí estás haciendo referencia a que vas a crear un Objeto de tipo "Persona" pero vacío, porque no le pasas parámetros.

```
public Persona (String nombre, int edad);
```

Aquí estás definiendo dentro de esa clase que PARA construir a una persona necesitas 2 parámetros.

Imagínate esta clase:

```
class Persona {

  private String dni;
  private String nombre;
  private int edad;

  public Persona(){} // Sin parámetros

  public Persona(String documento,String nombre){ // 2 parámetros
    this.dni = documento;
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  public Persona(String dni,String nombre, int anyos){ // todos los parámetros
    this.dni = dni;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = anyos
  }


  public String saludar(){
    return "la persona: " + this.nombre + " te da la bienvenida"; 
  }

 // GETTERS, SETTERS...

}
```

Ahora, ¿de qué sirve esto?

Imagínate que tienes que crear una persona que tiene, 60 atributos en vez de 3 ... y dichos atributos no los conoces ahora,
Sino que esos valores los obtendrás 200 líneas después, para este caso

```
Persona per = new Persona();
```

Créalo vacío y con el tiempo, irás rellenando los valores.

```
   per.setNombre("Lara");
   etc
```

En caso contrario, conoces TODOS los valores y quieres crearla directamente con todos los datos.

```
Persona per = new Persona(dni,nombre,edad);
```

También puedes hacer:

```
Persona per = new Persona("1a");
```

Esto último te dará error, porque no se ha definido que se crearán Personas con 1 parámetro.

Además de todo lo anterior explicado, se recomienda (obligatorio), tener siempre el constructor por defecto(vacío) y si estás
usando base de datos, necesitarás el constructor con todos los parámetros para obtener todos los valores de la tabla.

Finalmente para llamar a los métodos de una clase, el ejemplo completo sería:

```
Persona per = new Persona ("1a","edu"); --> has creado 1 persona llamada edu
System.out.println(per.saludar()); --> edu te saluda
```

Si lo haces con

```
Persona per = new Persona (); --> has creado a una persona "vacía"->null.
System.out.println(per.saludar());
```

Cuando se haga this.nombre , como no tiene valor, se mostrará null.

Comment: Por qué es obligatorio tener un contructor sin parámetros?

Comment: @E.Betanzos Si la clase tiene un constructor parametrizado y en algún momento se quiere instanciar la clase sin tener que pasar ningún argumento al constructor, en ese caso, el constructor por defecto sería obligatorio agregarlo en dicha clase, de lo contrario, dará error de compilación. Al parecer a EduBw le faltó explicar ese detalle.

Comment: @MrDave1999 pero de ninguna manera es obliatorio ni siquiera recomendado, siempre dependerá del diseño de tu clase. Si por ejemplo quieres diseñar una clase teniendo como meta que las instancias de esta sean inmutables el constructor sin parámetros tiene que ser obligatoriamente eliminado.

Answer (score 1):

La línea de código donde tienes:

```
Persona humana = new Persona();
```

No es un constructor, es tu objeto `humana` la cual se convierte en la instancia de la clase persona.

Hacer lo anterior te va a permitir acceder con dicho objeto a los métodos y propiedades de la clase en cuestión.

Es decir algo mas o menos así:

```
humana.metodoUno();

humana.propiedadUno;
```

Mientras que el segundo caso donde tienes:

```
public Persona (String nombre, int edad)
```

Es el método constructor que en Java se debe llamar igual que la clase, este nos va a servir para indicar:

- El número de valores que la clase espera para asignar a las propiedades
- En el caso de Java al ser altamente tipado además deberás indicar el tipo de dato esperado

Lo anterior te va a ayudar a identificar entonces que el método constructor espera recibir 2 valores al momento de que la clase sea instanciada.

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia es que con Public void Persona() estas como por así decirlo definiendo la clase, es decir, estas indicando que informacion va a tener indicandolo en los atributos (En caso de persona pues nombre, altura, edad, etc).

En ese public puedes definir metodos que serían por así decirlo acciones que puedes hacer con el objeto (La persona en este caso) como podrian ser camiarEdad(), cambiarNombre(), etc.

Pero solo con eso estamos definiendo la clase y no estamos usando el objeto. Cuando queramos usar el objeto (Por ejemplo crear dos personas y compararlas) tendríamos que usar el:

```
Persona1 = new Persona();
Persona2= new Persona();
```

Lo que tiene que quedar claro es la diferencia entre definir una clase y los atributos y parametros que esta va a tener. Y usar los objetos. Inicializandolos en una variable.